# Pages 404ing when on https://

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I've just installed an SSL on my server and enabled https on my websites admin area however now when normal pages are accessed with https:// instead of http:// I get a 404 page. This is my htaccess, it has the standard expressionengine index.php removal in as well but I can't work out what I need to change to make https:// work if front-end pages are accessed with it, any ideas?:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # force https for all URLs in /admin.php
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
        RewriteRule ^admin.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        # Redirect index.php Requests
        # ------------------------------
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

        # Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
        # ------------------------------
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you show your `VirtualHost` config for `https` site?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't as we're on a shared host that won't give us access to this, I've request that the host send us this info tho!

Comment: Narrowed this down now, seems to be something to do with the index.php rewrite, if i goto https://domain.com/page it doesn't work, but if i goto https://domain.com/index.php/page it does work, any idea how I'd get the index.php rewrite working for both http and https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https for all URLs in /admin.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^admin\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, unfortunately this just results in exactly the same problem though, but it's a lot less code in our htaccess!

Comment: I am suspecting your `https` requests are not even hitting this .htaccess (due to different `DocumentRoot` in `VirtualHost`). To test this put same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and then open `https://domain.com/index.php/page` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Looks like that's the case, thanks I'll update the virtualhost settings!

Comment: You're welcome, that was the reason I commented on `VirtualHost` settings first.